# Display content of columns at same level/ height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have column in a div set to `display:flex`. All the columns are centered. The column contents are all `vertical-align: middle;`

It works great when the content is all of the same height (see snippet). But when one column is taller than the others, I want the shorter columns to be at the same level/ height as the tallest column as in my image below, whilst the tallest column remains vertically in the middle:
[image]

Is this possible using css or javascript?

```css
.cont { height:400px;  width: 100% }
.button-bottom {display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center; height:50%;background: yellow;}

.column {width: 20%;
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
float: none;}
```

```html
<div class="cont">  
  <div class="button-bottom">
     <div class="column">
       <h5>Ambience Blah BLha mana na hhsjs</h5>
     </div>
    <div class="column">
       <h5>Ambience</h5>
     </div>
    <div class="column">
       <h5>Ambience</h5>
     </div>
    <div class="column">
       <h5>Ambience</h5>
     </div>
    <div class="column">
     <h5>Ambience</h5>
     </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I do this for the points. Here's your fix.

```css
.cont { height:400px;  width: 100% }
.button-bottom {display: flex;
justify-content: center; height:50%;background: yellow;}
.column {width: 20%;
display: table-cell;
float: none;}
```

```html
<div class="cont">  
  <div class="button-bottom">
     <div class="column">
       <h5>Ambience Blah BLha mana na hhsjs</h5>
     </div>
    <div class="column">
       <h5>Ambience</h5>
     </div>
    <div class="column">
       <h5>Ambience</h5>
     </div>
    <div class="column">
       <h5>Ambience</h5>
     </div>
    <div class="column">
     <h5>Ambience</h5>
     </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @catbadger Thanks for attempting this. But your solution makes all the content go to the top. I still want the tallest content to stay vertically in the middle.

Answer (score -1):

https://jsfiddle.net/ex3ntia/r67y6hhu/3/

I've added 2 css lines that you can delete

```
/* demo */
h5 {position:relative;}
.column h5:before {display:block;background-color:red;content:'';width:100%;height:2px;top:15px;position:absolute;}
```

Comment: Please always comment when you down vote or is useless